# How to set background color for each item listview depanding on variable value

Tags: android, listview

I have a very simple question but Google does not show me a proper answer. I need to setBackground color for each item in my `listview` depanding on variable value. `handle` status item needs to be one color and `done` has to be another.

Listview adapter

```
class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String[] time;
String[] clientName;
String[] district;
String[] address;
String[] goods;
String[] price;
String[] status;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] time, String[] clientName, String[] district, String[] address, String[] goods, String[] price, String[] status) {
    this.context = context;
    this.time = time;
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.district = district;
    this.address = address;
    this.goods = goods;
    this.price = price;
    this.status = status;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return clientName.length; // было 0
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView txtclientName;
    TextView txttime;
    TextView txtdistrict;
    TextView txtaddress;
    TextView txtgoods;
    TextView txtprice;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    txtclientName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clientNameSingle);
    txttime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeSingle);
    txtdistrict = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.districtSingle);
    txtaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressSingle);
    txtgoods = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.goodsSingle);
    txtprice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceSingle);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtclientName.setText(clientName[position]);
    txttime.setText(time[position]);
    txtdistrict.setText(district[position]);
    txtaddress.setText(address[position]);
    txtgoods.setText(goods[position]);
    txtprice.setText(price[position]);

    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF7F"));

    return itemView;
}
}
```

Orderlist class

```
public class OrderList extends Activity {

ListView list;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
String[] time;
String[] clientName;
String[] district;
String[] address;
String[] goods;
String[] price;
String[] status;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

    time = new String[]{"09:00", "09:00"};
    clientName = new String[]{"Анна", "Ольга"};
    district = new String[]{"Калининский", "Калининский"};
    address = new String[]{"Морская набережная д35", "Проспект Непокоренных 49"};
    goods = new String[]{"Елка 1.8м", "Сосна 2м"};
    price = new String[]{"1499", "2299"};
    status = new String[]{"done", "handle"};

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, time, clientName, district, address, goods, price, status);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Animation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
            animation1.setDuration(2000);
            view.startAnimation(animation1);


            Intent intent = new Intent(OrderList.this, SingleItemView.class);
            intent.putExtra("time", time);
            intent.putExtra("clientName", clientName);
            intent.putExtra("district", district);
            intent.putExtra("address", address);
            intent.putExtra("goods", goods);
            intent.putExtra("price", price);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            intent.putExtra("status", status);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want the entire row in the `ListView` set to a certain color or just on of the `TextView` objects?

Comment: I want to set color for entire row

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer. This will give a step-by-step example. Please be advised that you will need to make some changes to best suit your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to set the color of one of the rows in the `ListView` then you can do this:

In your ListView Layout "listview_item" give the root layout an id. Eg. "rlMainLayout"

In your `getView` method you need to get a reference to the layout object. If it is a RelativeLayout then it would look something like this:

```
final RelativeLayout rlMainLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlMainLayout);
```

Now you can set the color to your `RelativeLayout` object like this:

```
rlMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

**----------------------------------------------------------**

**-- EDIT --**

**A STEP-BY-STEP EXAMPLE**

*(Please be advised that I did this in a Text Editor program .. so there could be some typos. )*

You will need to alter your custom adapter class. Important: You will want to use a model class (in this case called MyListData). It will help when you need to maintain your software to separate your model from your views.

```
public class MyListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListData> {

    private static final String TAG = "MyListDataAdapter";


    public MyListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyListData> data) {
        super(context, 0, data);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final MyListData data = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView txtclientName;
        TextView txttime;
        TextView txtdistrict;
        TextView txtaddress;
        TextView txtgoods;
        TextView txtprice;

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtclientName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clientNameSingle);
        txttime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeSingle);
        txtdistrict = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.districtSingle);
        txtaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressSingle);
        txtgoods = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.goodsSingle);
        txtprice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceSingle);

        RelativeLayout rlMainLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlMainLayout);
        Color originalColorValue = tvNumberOfItems.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtclientName.setText(data.getClientName());
        txttime.setText(data.getTime());
        txtdistrict.setText(data.getDistrict());
        txtaddress.setText(data.getAddress());
        txtgoods.setText(data.getGoods());
        txtprice.setText(data.getPrice());

        if(data.getIsSelected){
            rlMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else{
            rlMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(originalColorValue);
        }

        return itemView;
    }

}
```

Now you need a model class to hold the data. Let's call it MyListData (But you call it what you like)

```
public class MyListData {

    // Add more as you need
    // I have used the ones you have defined...
    private String time;
    private String clientName;
    private String district;
    private String address;
    private String goods;
    //... but I think price should be of type double so that you can do calculations if needed
    private String price;
    private String status;
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public MyListData(){
    }


    public void setTime(String time){ this.time = time; }
    public void setClientName(String clientName){ this.clientName = clientName; }
    public void setDistrict(String district){ this.district = district; }
    public void setAddress(String address){ this.address = address; }
    // TODO: !! ..Please add the others goods, price, status ..
    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected){ this.isSelected = isSelected; }

    // Now add your public getters!!
    public String getTime(){ return this.time; }
    public String getClientName(){ return this.setClientName; }
    // TODO: !! ... Please add the others for goods, price, status...
    public boolean getIsSelected(){ return this.isSelected; }

}
```

Your custom `ListView` layout could look something like the following. Please notice the root layout has an identifier `rlMainLayout`!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/rlMainLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
            android:text="address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity (eg. in the `onCreate()` method) where the `ListView` you will need to populate the data for the `ListView`. This should **not** be done on the UI Thread

```
    // This will contain all the data you need from you model class in an ArrayList
    ArrayList<MyListData> arrayListData = new ArrayList<MyListData>();
    MyListDataAdapter adapter = new MyListDataAdapter(this, arrayListData);

    for (MyListData g : result) {
        adapter.add(g);
    }
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also in the activity where the `ListView` is to be maintained set up some `onClick` event handlers if you need them:
(I find that one of the small advantages of the `ListView` is that the `onClick` event is easier it implement than in the `RecycleView`)

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
        MyListData data = (MyListData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        data.setIsSelected = true;

        // Update the listview with the changes to your MyListData
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

Comment: I   need to set color depanding on variable value.
Something like that in getView()


if (status.equals("done")){
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF7F"));
        }

but this code doing nothing(even no error)

Comment: Which code is doing nothing?  Your code.. ::  `itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF7F"));`   Or the code I suggested?  ::   `rlMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` ?? My code has worked for me in several Android projects.

Comment: rlMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); will set color to whole table, but Im looking for way to set color depanding on variable "status" from Orderlist class

Comment: rlMainLayout should be the root layout for your custom row xml file `listview_item`. That way when your custom adapter class inflates your custom row layout `listview_item` the object rlMainLayout  has reference to the layout for that row! All you need to do is set a conditional to set ONLY those rows you want to set to a different color. You could put a bool value in your model class to indicate which datasets need to be set the different color. Your model class should hold references to all the data:: time, clientName, district, address, goods,...

Answer (score 0):

Hope your using Layout inside your listview_item layout file 
Once your initialising in the adapter file you can replace the background color for the layout

```
int[] color = {R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.colorAccent,R.color.colorPrimaryDark};

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.listview_item);

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color[2]);
```