# Get primary key when clicking on one item on listview

Tags: android, listview

If I populate my `listview` with the primary key of my table I can get this primary key using `getItemAtPosition` and then it works fine.

The problem is that I don't want to use the `primarykey` to populate de listview, instead I want to use other fields of my table. Doing that, when I use the getItemAtPosition comand, because itsn't unic I can't use this to select my register.

I thought about using `getItemIdAtPosition` but I didn't reached any solution.

```
public void populateListView() {
        //get the data and append to the list
        Cursor data = db.getAllDataFillup(selectedID);
        ArrayList<String> listData2 = new ArrayList<>();


        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            //listData2.add("FILLUP_ID: " + data.getString(0) + "    FILLUP_VEHICLE_ID: " + data.getString(1));
            //listData2.add(data.getString(7) + " " + data.getString(8) + " " + data.getString(2));
            listData2.add(data.getString(3));
            //listData2.add(data.getString(2));

        }



        //create the list adapter and set the adapter

        ListAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData2);
        list_fillup.setAdapter(adapter2);


        //set onItemClickListener to the listView
        list_fillup.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int fillupID = Integer.parseInt(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());

                long position = adapterView.getSelectedItemId();
                //long a = list_fillup.get(codigoDoObjeto).getCodigoIdOuPKQualquer();



                toastMessage("position:  " + position);
                //toastMessage("fillupPosition:  " + fillupPosition);
                //long fillupPosition = adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);

                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + fillupID);


                Cursor data = db.getDataTableFillup(fillupID);//get the data associated with that fillupID

                fillupID = -1;
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    fillupID = data.getInt(0);
                    vehicleID = data.getInt(1);
                    fillupDate = data.getString(2);
                    odometer = data.getLong(3);
                    kmDriven = data.getLong(4);
                    liters = data.getLong(5);
                    consumption = data.getLong(6);
                    label = data.getString(7);
                    sequence = data.getInt(8);
                }
                if (fillupID > -1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + fillupID);
                    Intent screenVehicle = new Intent(Vehicle_painel.this, Fillup_edit.class);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("fillupID", fillupID);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("vehicleID", vehicleID);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("vehicleName", selectedName);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("date", fillupDate);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("odometer", odometer);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("kmDriven", kmDriven);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("liters", liters);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("consumption", consumption);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("label", label);
                    screenVehicle.putExtra("sequence", sequence);

                    //toastMessage("fillupPosition:  " + fillupPosition);
                    startActivity(screenVehicle);

                } else {
                    toastMessage("fillupID = " + fillupID);
                    //db.deleteAllFillup(selectedID);
                    //toastMessage("No ID associated with that name hahaha");
                }
```

Comment: Do you want to get list selected postion?

Comment: Not the position on the list, but the primary key from my table.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to create a custom class to hold your data. That way you no longer just get a simple `String` value back from your adapter. Your `ArrayList` would be something like:

```
ArrayList<YourCustomClass> listData2 ...
```

Create a custom class "YourCustomClass" (Call it what ever you like). It could look like:

```
 public class YourCustomClass {

    private long itemId = 0;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemDescription;

    public YourCustomClass(){
    }


    public void setItemId(long id){ this.itemId = id; }
    public void setItemName(String itemName){ this.itemName = itemName; }
    public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription){ this.itemDescription = itemDescription; }

    public long getItemId() { return this.itemId; }
    public String getItemName(){ return this.itemName; }
    public String getItemDescription(){ return this.itemDescription; }
}
```

Now in your `onItemClick` method get the Id and the other data like this:

```
YourCustomClass data = (YourCustomClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
long orderId = data.getItemId();
String name = data.getItemName();
```

You will need a custom adapter to populate your `ListView` with data.

**You can also take a look at this answer. It shows how to change the background color of a `ListView` item, but also shows more detail of how to implement a custom adapter for your `ListView`.**

[How to set background color for each item listview depanding on variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189818/how-to-set-background-color-for-each-item-listview-depanding-on-variable-value/47190129#47190129)